# Highest DEM pixel in polygon

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, dem

I'm working with QGIS and have a big DEM raster layer with height information and a vector layer with many polygons, representing 1 x 1 degree tiles. Now I want to find for every polygon the highest value of the DEM pixels in it.

Answer (score 5):

Try *SAGA module* **Shapes - Grid -> Grid statistics for polygons** - directly or via QGIS:

[image: Grid statistics for polygons]

One of statistics is *Maximum* - so the result will meet your expectations.

Resulting table will be your input table with new columns named after statistics used in module (as far as I remeber SAGA doesn't obey the 8 character fieldnames limitation for shp - but you can edit it later).

Comment: Is SAGA a conventional plugin, because I don't find it in the plugin list.

Comment: Yes, since QGIS 2.0 (I guess) SAGA modules are implemented in QGIS. Check at the menu bar _Geoprocessing_ then open _Tools_ there you'll find SAGA modules.

Comment: Thank you very much, it messed the job a little bit up (it created more values than needed with confusing notations), but it has done the important part. :)

Comment: In what way did it mess the job? Did it create more columns when you'd chosen only _Maximum statistics_? As I warned You before: SAGA name fields quite badly (long names like GRIDNAME [statistics name]), then it's shortened to fullify shp standard (8 char fieldname)). Was that the problem?

Comment: FYI, in my SAGA in QGIS 3.8 it's now called "Raster statistics for polygons".